# How to vertically line up PlainTexts in a few horizontal pairs of caption+edit?

Tags: android, layout

I have a layout as in the picture, without the red line. As you can see, the PlainText input fields left sides are not alighed. Even worse, they position themselves differently for different languages depending on caption lengths. How can I make them start at the same offset?
PS. I need it to work at least on Android Jelly Bean 4.3.x  API level 18.

[image]
My relevant layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".WriteTagNumberActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:freezesText="true"
                android:text="@string/autoincrement"
                app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/editText2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="112dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:freezesText="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/write_tag_number_number"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:numeric="integer"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
                android:singleLine="true"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/checkBox"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout12"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout13">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView15"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/team_name" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:freezesText="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout14"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout12">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView17"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/group_name" />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/editText14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:freezesText="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint=" "
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using LinearLayout inside ConstraintLayout, try using chaining and barriers. You should always avoid using nested layout inside ConstraintLayout, since it defeats the purpose of flat hierarchy introduced by ConstraintLayout ( https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/understanding-performance-benefits-of.html )

https://riggaroo.co.za/constraintlayout-guidelines-barriers-chains-groups/

https://constraintlayout.com/basics/barriers.html

Comment: Thanks! Even basic vertical guidelines do the job for me.

Comment: The guideline might work for your device, but when you test your layout with different language and different android system font size, the guideline might not work as expected.